# How to ask someone to speed up a delayed task in a polite but solid way?

Tags: conversation

Consider you paying someone to do something for you at a specific time. But the person does not aim to reach the agreed time. What is the most professional way to ask him to adhere to the deadline?

These are some ways I can think of, but they don't seem as strong or as polite as I need.

- Smith, I expect to receive the report by Friday.
- Smith, I need the report by Friday.
- Smith, Let's get the report ready by Friday.
- Smith, I hoped to get the report last Monday. Can you update me on it?

Comment: I CV'd because this question seems to be asking people to write a new sentence for OP's use, and that's not really what ELL is for (as I understand it).

Comment: 'A delayed takes'? Do you mean 'task'? Remind him that his contract requires the work to be done by Friday.

Comment: @HandsomeNerd Closing off-topic questions *does* help the community, it just doesn't help you. If you want to argue that your question is not off-topic, this is the place to do so. But there's no point in reframing his close vote on your question as a disservice to the community.

Comment: @HandsomeNerd There was a small push earlier this years for CV'ers to explain their reasons, thus benefiting askers. Comments like yours discourage people from explaining CV's, which won't stop people from CV'ing but will cause them to stop posting their reasons, which would be a disservice to the community. So instead of complaining, please consider the comment in a constructive way. And of course feel free to ask if you have any questions about my comment; I'm always happy to engage!

Comment: @MarcInManhattan ok, I believe the questions are highly related and essentially the main point of this site. We don't learn a language just to know it. We learn a language to communicate with the speakers of the language, to express ourselves so they understand us. In your comment, you said, "this question seems to be asking people to write a new sentence". It's not clear where you get this from. Many non-native speakers are not aware of the connotations or better expressions that natives use. Your comment devalued the question and neglected these fundamental facts.

Comment: @HandsomeNerd You wrote, "What is the most professional way to ask him to adhere to the deadline?" To answer that, I think that someone would have to either edit an existing sentence or make up a new one. You provided four sentences but rejected them with no indication that you wanted them edited. (Of course, ELL isn't a free editing service, either.) That's why I concluded that an answerer would likely have to make up a new sentence.

Comment: The question seems very clear to me.  The asker is asking which of four options has a particular characteristic in tone. Nowhere do they ask us for additional suggestions (but many other questions here do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the four options,

> Smith, I hoped to get the report last Monday. Can you update me on it?

the fourth one has the most professional, and "polite but solid tone".   The speaker reminds the listener of the task, expresses disappointment, and asks for an update so that they can better set future expectations.

The first two:

> Smith, I expect to receive the report by Friday.

> Smith, I need the report by Friday.

are probably too strong, and the listener might react negatively or believe that the speaker is extremely upset.

> Smith, Let's get the report ready by Friday.

is polite, but might be seen as a suggestion rather than communicating a deadline.

Answer (score -1):

All of these are valid. All are fairly polite ways of expressing the idea. The fourth is a little stronger.